Problem installing turtlesim package on Windows
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.11.42
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation

[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'

C:\Windows\System32> cd C:\dev\ros2_ws

C:\dev\ros2_ws>call ..\ros2_jazzy\local_setup.bat

C:\dev\ros2_ws>colcon build --symlink-install --merge-install
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_async_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_service
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_async_client
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 3.10 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.

Update the VERSION argument value. Or, use the ... syntax
to tell CMake that the project requires at least but has been updated
to work with policies introduced by or earlier.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/dev/ros2_jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py", line 21, in
from ament_package.templates import get_environment_hook_template_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'
CMake Error at C:/dev/ros2_jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message):
execute_process(C:/Python38/python.exe
C:/dev/ros2_jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py
C:/dev/ros2_ws/build/examples_rclcpp_async_client/ament_cmake_package_templates/templates.cmake)
returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/dev/ros2_jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_coreConfig.cmake:41 (include)
C:/dev/ros2_jazzy/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:15 (find_package)
C:/dev/ros2_jazzy/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmakeConfig.cmake:41 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)

Failed <<< examples_rclcpp_async_client [16.8s, exited with code 1]
Aborted <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client [16.7s]
Aborted <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher [16.6s]
Aborted <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_service [16.5s]
Aborted <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server [16.7s]
Aborted <<< examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor [16.8s]
Aborted <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_client [16.7s]
Aborted <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition [16.9s]

Summary: 0 packages finished [17.4s]
1 package failed: examples_rclcpp_async_client
7 packages aborted: examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_service
8 packages had stderr output: examples_rclcpp_async_client examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_service
14 packages not processed
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)

C:\dev\ros2_ws>

